# Unable to restrict access to AWS API even after calling globalsignout Method using javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS API gateway for API's and cognito UserPool's for security. After Authenticating the user we will get tokens and I am using that token to authorise my API.

Now, I am trying to enable signout to cognito authorised users using javascript. Used the below code.

```
if (cognitoUser != null) {
          cognitoUser.globalSignOut({   
                           onFailure: e =>   console.log(e), 
                           onSuccess: r =>   
               console.log('Logout success: ' + r)  
})}
```

I am getting response as success but still I am able to access my API with the previous tokens.Please suggest me how to inactivate all the tokens issued to that cognito user.

Answer (score 3):

The id token, which API Gateway uses to authenticate API calls, stays valid for a while.

I would test for the access token. It should expire right after you call global sign out.

The key word is *should* above. Please see [this issue](https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/21). It’s an on-going struggle to get AWS to implement an immediate revocation. Here’s a relevant quote:

> I worked with AWS Cognito team to get this taken care and got released as a fix through CLI as following.

```
aws cognito-identity update-identity-pool --identity-pool-id --identity-pool-name --allow-unauthenticated-identities --cognito-identity-providers ProviderName=,ClientId=,ServerSideTokenCheck=<true|false>
```

> By setting the ServerSideTokenCheck to true on a Cognito Identity
>   Pool, that Identity Pool will check with Cognito User Pools to make
>   sure that the user has not been globally signed out or deleted before
>   the Identity Pool provides an OIDC token or AWS credentials for the
>   user. Now we are running into another issue of this Token being cached
>   in API Gateway for 10mins which would let that OID token still be
>   active for 10mins even though the User has globally signed out.

Here's what I mean by test for the accessToken (I have had success with method #2):

1.) you could develop a [custom authorizer for API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/integrating-amazon-cognito-user-pools-with-api-gateway/);

2.) you could perform a check at the start of your lambda functions or on your servers, using:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const awsConfig = require('./awsConfig');

const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider(awsConfig);

// accessToken provided from API Gateway

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  cognito.getUser({ accessToken }, (errorCallback, response) => {
    if (errorCallback) {
      reject(errorCallback);
    } else {
      resolve(response);
    }
  });
});
```

The errorCallback and response do not matter. If you get an error, the token is invalid. If you don’t, it’s valid.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I changed my configuration in api gateway. So, now i can access API using AccessToken not with Id Token. Now, I called globalsignout method. After that I tested with my previous accesstoken to validate my API. Still my token is not expired. Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: I have used method #2 above in a project, and it has worked. I am less familiar with method #1 implementations. As a test, if possible, I would see if method #2 works on a Lambda function, or on your server. If so, I’ll change my answer. I would just got for method #2. There is a known issue with a delay in access token revocation. I’ll post in my answer above.